# MUI data grid getRowModels returns map not an array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is the object returned in console.log()
[image]

My question why it is not returning an array? I cannot even map this data.
I just want to get all rows in the data grid.

```
    const handleSave = () => {
        console.log(apiRef.current.getRowModels());
    };
```

Comment: It is defined in the [GridApi](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-api/#main-content) in the MUI docs. To convert the set you could use `Array.from(yourSet)`